# Mapping getting created in elastic search even if dynamic mapping is disabled

Tags: elasticsearch, dynamic, indexing, mapping

I have disabled dynamic mapping in `elasticsearch.yml` using command `index.mapper.dynamic:false`, still the mapping is getting created on index creation. I am using elastic search version - `2.1.0`. How do I resolve this mapping in order to avoid error - `Error 400 (Bad Request): failed to parse [mykey] [type=mapper_parsing_exception]"`. Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to upgrade elastic search for this to work.

There is a bug logged for ES version 2.1.0 having the same issue which looks like it is fixed.
(https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15381)

If upgrading is a problem, you can disable dynamic mapping while creating the index. Have a look at [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/dynamic-mapping.html)